# MySQL Commands into .DBF Tables

Tags: java, mysql, visual-foxpro

I am currently writing a database system in Java that writes and reads to a MySQL database hosted on XAMPP. The system is fully up and running using MySQL commands to select, update, add, delete etc.

The issue is that we are currently using an old database written in Visual FoxPro that has its tables stored as .DBF files. Rather than taking a few years to get a fully working system and then moving everybody over to the MySQL system at once, we would like to have both systems working concurrently with gradually more people beginning to move over and use the MySQL system.

This is where I am having issues. Is there a way to both update a MySQL table and .DBF file when a job is added through the Java program? Is it as simple as using a MySQL command to directly modify the file? I understand there could be possibilities in Python or PHP however I have never learnt either of these languages and would prefer an easier solution.

Comment: yea... don't do that. it's more trouble than it's worth. What you should do is a one-time migration to MySQL. And if you need "Years to get a fully working system" after a Database migration, you're doing things wrong. With properly abstracted database access, you should be finished in a month at worst.

Comment: There is no such thing like "DBF standard" but de facto few versions. Generally using DBF without index at level similar to CSV is quite simple and few open source libraries exist. can't build relations, cant "select * from " etc ... package com.linuxense.javadbf but have no opinion in hard work

Comment: Commercial solution with jdbc, sql parser, indexes (maybe transactions) exsit, too much $ for my needs. Suppose: will be incompatible with Your existing software because of networking model.

Comment: @Vogel612 I agree. To jbanks You should rethink concurrency etc during transformation period, how many concurrent users has old system, how much dynamically add/update data.

Comment: @Vogel612, these are fairly large database files for a small-medium sized company. Their current FoxPro interfafce is extremely complicated and this is my first real commercial-grade solution that I need to write. Is it really going to be considerably mroe complicated to have the two solutions working side by side?

Comment: @Vogel612: without knowing what the existing system does, how can you possibly say that replicating it shouldn't take more than a month. The existing system may have been built over two decades using thousands or tens of thousands of person-hours and may have all kinds of complex capabilities.

Comment: @TamarE.Granor "With properly abstracted database access" and "migrate from database 1 to database 2" ... That's the two prequisites for that. And even with some leaking abstractions a month should be more time than necessary. Replicating a whole system? I never said anything about that.

Comment: @Vogel612: If the original database were client-server, you'd have a point. but DBFs are native to Visual FoxPro and there's a built-in data access mechanism that's not SQL. It's likely that an old application relies heavily on that mechanism, and would require significant changes to switch to a SQL database.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to keep two databases in synch is a bad idea. If you miss something and the data no longer matches, how will you know which is right? (A man with one clock always knows what time it is; a man with two is never sure.)

If the existing system is complex enough, maybe consider moving one module at a time.

If the existing system is well-written, it might be possible to switch it to work with MySQL without too much effort. That said, my experience is that very few applications are well enough designed and written to make that a simple task.

Alternatively, you might set up your new system with some kind of wrapper that talks to the existing DBFs until you're done and then can easily switch to MySQL.